# Unable to install egit plugin in eclipse galileo

Tags: java, eclipse, git, egit, galileo

I have an git URI and I want to import that project into Eclipse.

From [this post](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGit/article.html) I learned that we need to need to install the egit software in Eclipse.
But when I try to install this software I get the following error messages:

[image]

I am just thinking is the repository for egit moved to other place or are there any compatibility issues? I am totally not sure.

I am using Eclipse Galileo Platform Version: 3.5.2 Build id: M20100211-1343.
Is anybody there who encountered the same problem??

**UPDATE  -- This is the full error message**

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Eclipse Git Team Provider 4.2.0.201601211800-r (org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 4.2.0.201601211800-r)
  Missing requirement: Eclipse Git Team Provider 4.2.0.201601211800-r (org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 4.2.0.201601211800-r) requires 'org.eclipse.core.runtime [3.7.0,4.0.0)' but it could not be found
```

Comment: Well Galileo is very old, EGit may need something a lot newer. We need to see the full Details messages.

Comment: @greg-449 I updated the post!!!!!

Comment: Eclipse is now on version 4.5. The error message is clearly stating that that version of EGit requires a 3 series of 3.7 or later. Is there a particular reason you can't use a modern version?

Answer (score 3):

The key part of the error is

```
requires 'org.eclipse.core.runtime [3.7.0,4.0.0)'.
```

This is saying that the `org.eclipse.core.runtime` plugin must be at least version 3.7.0 (and below 4.0.0).

The version of `org.eclipse.core.runtime` in Eclipse Galileo is 3.5.0 so this version of EGit cannot be installed on Galileo. Either move to a newer Eclipse or try and find an older EGit (I don't know if a suitable version exists).

Comment: A list of older EGit releases and their repositories can be found here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/FAQ#Where_can_I_find_older_releases_of_EGit.3F

Comment: @greg-449 So shall I download newer version of eclipse. Do you think the problem will get resolved?

Comment: EGit definitely runs on the current version of Eclipse, in fact I think many of the downloads include it pre-installed.

Comment: The version of egit compatible with Eclipse Galileo (3.6.2, etc) is http://archive.eclipse.org/egit/updates-2.1/